# API Gateway と Lambda の入力マッピングについて

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

他の人の作った ApiGateway + Lambda があるのですがパラメータの渡し方がわかりません

統合リクエストが Lambda で
マッピングテンプレートが以下のようになっている場合
curl でどう叩けばこの Lambda が起動できますか

```
{
    "yearA": "$input.params('year')",
    "monthA": "$input.params('month')",
    "dayA": "$input.params('day')",
    "bodyA": $input.body
}
```

受け取り側の Lambda はこんな感じでコメントを見ると JSON で渡すように見えます

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # {'yearA': 2020, 'monthA': 8, 'dayA': 10, 'bodyA': {'user_id': 'jjkjkjkjuiuhjkhkjhkjh'}}
    print(event)
```

`curl -XPOST -v https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/staging/2019/11/12`
だと Lambda には到達して yearA monthA dayA は取得できるんですが 'bodyA': {} となります

それ以外は以下のようなPOSTパラメータを試してみたんですが全て Unsupported Media Type となって Lambda に到達できません

```
-d '{"user_id":"test"}'
-d 'user_id=test'
-F '{"user_id":"test"}'
-F 'user_id=test'
```

Comment: 質問を読む限り、マッピングテンプレートはPOST等bodyを扱うリクエスト用に定義されているのに実際にはGETしか受け付けていない、またはPOSTのハンドラは定義されていないように見えます。/1. 今回、特に自分ではAPI Gateway等の構成は何も弄っていない、ということですか？2. GET以外にPUTなどのエンドポイント（というかメソッド）は設定されてませんか？

Comment: すみません。 curl のコピペミスで実際はオプションなしの時は -XPOST を付けていました。-d, -F のときはなくても POST 扱いされるため。おそらくリソースがない場合 {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} となると思うのでリソースは正しい、というかアプリから呼ばれて運用されているので curl での叩き方が知りたいです

Comment: なるほど読み違えてた箇所理解。マッピングのコンテンツタイプがどう設定されているのかは存じませんが、-dでJSONを投げるときにヘッダを明示していないと `content-type`ヘッダーが`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`になります。 `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` などのように指定した場合はどうなりますか？確かにそれなら適切なエラーメッセージ返されてますね。

Comment: まさにそれでした。application/jsonにしたら Lambda にパラメータを渡せました！　確かに  Unsupported Media Type と言われてるので ContentType を疑って然るべきでしたが考えに至りませんでした

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON をペイロードとして curl でリクエストを送る場合、Content-Typeヘッダーでそれを明示してやる必要があります。

```
curl https://example.com -d -d '{"user_id":"test"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

---

なお、API Gatewayでは構成の設定次第でJSON(デフォルト)以外にもXMLなども選べるようですが、とりあえずデフォルトはJSONの模様。ところで `$input.body` だと文字列のままで `$input.json('$')` であるべきだったのでは等と思ったり…… ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference))

*コメントで一応解決しているようですが回答として投稿。*